# Wrap text inside div

Tags: html, css

I want to desing a div like follows-

[image]

the code for this div is as follows

```
    <div style='width:132.5px; height:158px;background-color:#cccccc;display:block;float:left;margin:3px'>
  <div style='background-color:#cccccc;width:100%;height:50%;float:top;color: black;'>
    <span style = 'font-style:bold;font-size:18.5px;line-height: -moz-block-height;width:100%;height:100%;'>Gross Margin Amount
    </span>
  </div>
<div style='background-color:#dddddd;font-style:bold;font-size:"+fontSize2+"px;line-height: -moz-block-height;text-align:center;width:100%;height:50%;color: white;float:bottom'>3,110
</div>
```

As you can see that text of the first div encroaching in the lower div.
I want to wrap the text inside the div.Is it possible??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you experienced how hard it is to do web design using inline styles? Is there any reason for you to do so?

Comment: Also, so far this is all I can see from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/pd55j3ek/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Actually i dont have much idea about web designing.This is someone else's code and I must have to correct it.So if you can propose a solution it would be very helpful!

Comment: Your `<div>` tags are unbalanced.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan now i have updated my code,you can see my problem on jsfiddle,could you please check now...

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `<div` tags are unbalanced. Maybe that already is your issue.

Apart from that you should use separate css styling to keep things readable. This is probably what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/bsdhze4a/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner top">Gross Margin Amount</div>
  <div class="inner bottom">3,110</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
}
div.inner.top {
    color: black;
    background-color: #759BA6;
}
div.inner.bottom {
    color: white;
    background-color: #084C61;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: My problem is that the div i need to design is part of a resizable div and all the values like font size and div width are coming dynamically,So i cannot just use this code in place of mine,I need to change that code only by adding word wrap property to make it work!!!!

Comment: @ValarDohaeris Certainly you can use my style rules as inline codes too. That way you can define them more dynamically if that really has to be done on the server side. I only used separate styling to keep things readable. It is unclear to me what you mean by "only word wrap".